# Wordpress sort WP ULike posts in custom query?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to implement this WP ULike plugin [sort example](https://github.com/Alimir/wp-ulike#how-to-sort-most-liked-posts) inside my custom query but no success so far as I'm not a WordPress pro. Any help is appreciated, thanks a lot!

My custom query:

```
$heroes_query = new WP_Query(
    array(          
        'posts_per_page' => 3,
        'post_type' => 'heroes',
        'order' => 'DESC'
    )
);
```

And this is from their documentation:

```
/**
 * Get most liked posts in query
 *
 * @param integer $numberposts      The number of items
 * @param array|string $post_type   Select post type
 * @param string $method            keep this as default value (post, comment, activity, topic)
 * @param string $period            Date peroid (all|today|yeterday|week|month|year)
 * @param string $status            Log status (like|unlike|dislike|undislike)
 * @return WP_Post[]|int[]          Array of post objects or post IDs.
 */
$wp_query = wp_ulike_get_most_liked_posts( 10, array( 'post' ), 'post', 'all', 'like' );
```

I also tried something from [this example](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/sort-most-liked-post-issue/) but still not working:

```
<?php 
        
        $heroes_query = new WP_Query(
        array(  
            $post__in = wp_ulike_get_popular_items_ids(array(
                'type'   => 'post',
                'status' => 'like',
                'period' => 'all'
            )),     
            'posts_per_page' => 3,
            'post__in' => $post__in,
            'post_type' => 'heroes',
            'orderby' => 'post__in',
            'order' => 'DESC'
            )
        ); ?>       
        <?php while ($heroes_query -> have_posts()) : $heroes_query -> the_post(); ?>           
            <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4">
                <?php get_template_part( 'loop-templates/content-card-hero' ); ?>
            </div><!-- /.col -->    
        <?php 
        endwhile;
        wp_reset_postdata();
        ?>
```

So what I want is to get the 3 most liked custom post types named "heroes". But this is what I get instead:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

thanks to your question, I managed to solve my problem. so I want to share with you the solution

```
$post__in = wp_ulike_get_popular_items_ids(array(
                'rel_type'   => 'heroes',
                'status' => 'like',
                'period' => 'all'
            )),
```

Comment: Code-only answers are not particularly helpful. Please add some descriptions of how this code solves the problem.

Comment: The author has a typo. 'type'   => 'post', This function wp_ulike_get_popular_items_ids() accepts parameters 'rel_type'   => 'POST_TYPE', where POST_TYPE, your wordpres post type, the author's is 'heroes'

Comment: Thanks for your help, but the sorting still does not work in my case. Does it work in your loop? Whether I type ASC or DESC they have the same order.